# What is Area of projection of curved circle?

Tags: geometry, area, projection

We all know that ellipse is projection of a circle that lies in the vertical projecting plane. And what about projection of curved circle? Is it ellipse? Or another shape.

[image]

Comment: It seems an ellipse at first view in your drawing. However it could be several positions of the projected circle. Your drawing assumes that there is some positional symmetry. In this case it would seem that there will be an ellipse that would have an axis equal to the radius R of the circle and another axis smaller than R. It would be interesting to prove, if possible, that the said projection complies with the defining locus property of an ellipse (constant sum of distances to two focus).